# Writing an ArrayAdapter dirrently - android

Tags: android, optimization, android-arrayadapter

So I'm writing a program that has three spinners and I want to add an array to each of them. However the code I have at the moment works but is very long so I was wondering if there is an easier/shorter/more efficient way to code it.

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.distanceType,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        distanceSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.areaType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.genderType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        genderSpinner.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

As you can see its basically the the same code repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a factory method to ease writing your custom adapters :

```
 public ArrayAdapter createSimpleAdapter(int itemsArrayId ) {
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, itemsArrayId,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
       return adapter;         
 }
```

Then the creations become as easy as :

```
 distanceSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.distanceType));
 areaSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.areaType));
 genderSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.genderType));
```